# Two dice problem "Two dice are repeatedly thrown until ..."

Tags: probability

Two dice are repeatedly thrown until neither of them shows the number 6. Find the probability that at the final throw at least one of the dice shows the number 5.

$$P(\text{at least one 5 at the last throw}) = \frac{P(\text{at least one 5 and no 6 at the last throw})}{P(\text{no 6 at the last throw})} = \frac{9}{25}$$

As I understand $P(\text{no 6 at the last throw}) = \frac{25}{36}$ but $P(\text{at least one 5 and no 6 at the last throw})= \text{?} $

Why is it correct? Where did 9 come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to "given that the roll has no $6's$, what is the probability that it has at least one $5$?"

Working backwards, the probability that the roll has no $5's$, given that it has no $6's$ is:  $$\left(\frac 45\right)^2=\frac {16}{25}$$

Accordingly, the desired result is $$1-\frac {16}{25}=\frac 9{25}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring throws in which a $6$ appears. So you may as well pretend that you have two $5$-sided dice. Then the probability that neither of them is $5$ is $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2$.

By the way, the expression $P(\text{no 6 at the last throw})$ is meaningless here $-$ the last throw is *defined* as the first throw with no $6$. So your equation makes no sense.